# Closed form of a recursive equation

Tags: algorithms, closed-form, recursion

I have an assignment where I need to bring the following recursive equation in a closed form:

$$R(n) = \dfrac{2}{n} \cdot (R(0) +R(1) +. . .+R(n−1)) + c$$

I can use

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{i(i+1)} = \dfrac{n}{n+1}$$

from a previous assignment.

So far I came to $nR(n)=2(R(0) +R(1) + \cdots +R(n−1)) + cn$

and then to

$(n-1)R(n-2)=2(R(0) +R(1) + \cdots +R(n−1)) + c(n-1)$

But I have no idea how to continue and how to use the other equation.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to just plot a few values:

$R(0) = 0$

$R(1) = \frac{2}{1} \cdot 0 + c = c$

$R(2) = \frac{2}{2} \cdot (0 + c) + c= 2c$

$R(3) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot (0 + c + 2c) + c = 3c$

$R(4) = \frac{2}{4} \cdot (0 + c + 2c + 3c) + c= 4c$

$R(5) = \frac{2}{5} \cdot (0 + c + 2c + 3c + 4c) + c= 5c$

Which strongly suggests that $R(n) = nc$. Let's prove it by induction:

**Base case**: $R(0) = 0 \cdot c = 0$, which is true. And likewise $R(1) = 1 \cdot c = c$, which is true.

**Inductive step**: For all $0<n$ up to this point, suppose $R(n) = c + \frac{2}{n} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}R(i) = nc$. Let's show that $R(n+1) = (n+1) \cdot c$

Then we have:

$$R(n+1) = c + \frac{2}{n+1} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n} R(i) = c + \frac{2}{n+1} \sum_{i=0}^{n}ic \\= c + \frac{2}{n+1} \cdot \frac{1}{2}cn(n + 1) = (n+1) \cdot c$$

Which proves the result.

Comment: Thank you very much !
We had an example in a global assignment lecture, which was way more complicated than your solution. 
Thanks as well for giving me the possibility for another approach to these kind of things.

Comment: I would love to, but I have less than 15 reputation :/

Comment: But isn't there a mistake at R(0) ?
2/0 can't be c.

Comment: It wasn't defined in the original post, but this solution assumes $R(0) = c$ (i.e. no previous values to take twice the mean, unlike the rest). Usually you are given / you need the base cases in order to derive an explicit closed-form.

Comment: I understand.
What would be, if R(0) = 0 ?

Comment: Then you'd have $R(n) = nc$

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I really proof nc with induction. I get the way with R(0)=0, R(1)=c and so on but not the way to proof it.

Comment: @Mattjo No worries. I changed the answer to show the inductive proof using $R(0) = 0$ instead of $c$

Comment: Thank you very much. You l, sir, are a legend